# What is the algorithm for finding the constraint force using the method of Lagrange multipliers?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

Is there a general procedure one can follow to find the force of constraint for a classical holonomic system with the nonconstraint forces derivable from a potential energy $U\left(\mathbf{r}_1, \dots , \mathbf{r}_n, t\right)$ where $\mathbf{r}_1, \dots , \mathbf{r}_n$ are the positions of the particles in an inertial reference frame? It seems that one can always find the force of constraint using the method of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) which I am not familiar with. If there is an algorithm for finding the force of constraint, what is it?

Comment: I don't mean this in a rude way, I really just want to understand. Are you just asking someone to explain to you how to use Lagrange multipliers to determine components of the constraint force? This is discussed in probably any mechanics book. What are you asking about that is not as clear?

Comment: @AaronStevens My question is really that general. I have a book that gives an example but an example isn't general.